# What does getSpeed() actually do inside of Android?

Tags: android, location

I am writing an app which uses the `onLocationChanged(Location location)` callback along with `location.getSpeed()` to get the speed at which the user is traveling.  I am curious as to what actually occurs when `getSpeed()` is called.  I note that `location` is just a parameter fed into the callback by Android, which leads me to wonder:

is `getSpeed()` simply pulling an already-calculated field from this object, or does calling `getSpeed()` calculate the value in some other way?

Answer (score 2):

I'm also curious many times what is in the source code or how is it called. I tried to find the code of android.Location class and it seems I'm succesfull. 
Try to check out this page: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/location/java/android/location/Location.java
The method 'getSpeed' is at the row number 627, but it tells only 'return mSpeed;', so you have to look to the other parts of the class

Comment: now i don't know if this is what you are searching for. hope this will help you. is that what you wanted?

Comment: As you said, we would have to look at other parts of the code, but it's definitely a step in the right direction.  Much thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Android's getSpeed() will just return the value that was set in setSpeed().

The best way to get speed is to use simple physics:

Speed = Distance/Time

The thing about GPS' is that there is a lot of variability and thus accuracy isn't always the best in terms of speed. You should use a filter to help smooth the data (The Kalman Filter is pretty popular for [navigation data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter)).

Good luck!

Comment: I'm not asking for help on getting the speed, it's reading properly.  I'm just curious as to what is going on behind the scenes from android's end.

Comment: Android's getSpeed() will just return the value that was set in setSpeed(), its just a variable.